# When was Machiavelli's Art of War first translated into Chinese?

Tags: translation, italian-language, niccolo-machiavelli, the-art-of-war-machiavelli

Bookeater recently asked [when Sun Zi's *Art of War* was first adopted outside China](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1100/2191). However, Sun Zi was not the only author who wrote a treatise on this topic. Machiavelli wrote [*Dell'arte della guerra* / *The Art of War*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_War_(Machiavelli)) around 1519-1520 and it was the only of his theoretical works that was printed during his lifetime.

My question is a bit like the reverse of Bookeater's question: When was Machiavelli's treatise *The Art of War* first translated into Chinese? A [simple web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=machiavelli+%22art+of+war%22+%22chinese+translation%22&t=ffsb&ia=web) did not help; I find mostly links about translations of Sun Zi's treatise ... Doing a search for 翻译 (the Chinese word for "translation") on the [Chinese Wikipedia article about Machiavelli](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E9%A6%AC%E5%9F%BA%E9%9B%85%E7%B6%AD%E5%88%A9) gives no results. A [search in Chinese](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%E5%85%B5%E6%B3%95+%E9%A9%AC%E5%9F%BA%E9%9B%85%E7%BB%B4%E5%88%A9+%E7%BF%BB%E8%AF%91&t=ffab&ia=web) brings up pages that I can't read with my basic level of Chinese.

Comment: I happen to know Chinese, and after finding no results on either WorldCat.org or the National Library of Taiwan website, I'm forced to conclude that it was never translated into Chinese; the Chinese title given on the Chinese Wikipedia page seems to be a rendering of convenience.

Comment: If you make some screenshots of search results from relevant library catalogues (also from mainland China), I'll think you can write up a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks for your vote of confidence, but I hesitate to answer without a smoking gun.

Comment: @CJSheu There appears to be a translation published by [The Commercial Press in 2012](https://max.book118.com/html/2017/1011/136772281.shtm). I found it using [this seach query: 马基雅维利 兵法 翻译](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%E9%A9%AC%E5%9F%BA%E9%9B%85%E7%BB%B4%E5%88%A9+%E5%85%B5%E6%B3%95+%E7%BF%BB%E8%AF%91&t=ffab&ia=web)

Answer (score 1):

The DuckDuckGo search [马基雅维利 兵法 翻译](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%E9%A9%AC%E5%9F%BA%E9%9B%85%E7%BB%B4%E5%88%A9+%E5%85%B5%E6%B3%95+%E7%BF%BB%E8%AF%91&t=ffab&ia=web) (literally: Machiavelli Art of War translation) gave the following page as the first search result: [兵法 - 尼科洛•马基雅维里.pdf](https://max.book118.com/html/2017/1011/136772281.shtm). The page contains a preview of a Chinese translation of Machiavelli's *Art of War* published by The Commercial Press in Beijing in 2012 (ISBN 978-7-100-09531-0).

Since CJ Sheu's searches on WorldCat.org and in the National Library of Taiwan's online catalogue got no results, I will assume that the above translation is the first one.